# Returning file path using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have a file dialog to open a file in `tkinter`. I am getting the file name using `tkinter` using `askopenfile()` as shown below. Now I want to be able to access the path to the file outside the `file_opener()` function.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
        
base = Tk()
base.geometry('150x150')
def file_opener():
    file = fd.askopenfile()
    if file:
        y = file.name

def file():
    f = open(y,'r') #Here i want to use value of y from above function 
    x = Button(base, text='Select a .txt/.csv file', command=lambda: file_opener())
    x.pack()
    mainloop()
```

Comment: Better use `askopenfilename()` instead of `askopenfile()` if you just want the filename.  For your case, simple fix is add `global y` inside `file_opener()` to make `y` a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `return` to return values. Modified code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog as fd

base = Tk()
base.geometry('150x150')
def file_opener():
    file = fd.askopenfile()
    if file:
        return file.name
def file():
    f=open(file_opener(),'r') #Here i want to use value of y from above function 
    print(f.read())
x = Button(base, text ='Select a .txt/.csv file', command = lambda:file())
x.pack()
mainloop()
```